# exception in running insert fiunction in hibernate application

Tags: java, hibernate

guys i am newbie in hibernate .. i am trying to run an insertion function in java using hibernate but it gives me exception .. any help .. thanks in advance
the exception

```html
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: namingStrategy
 at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.reset(AnnotationConfiguration.java:250)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:125)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:119)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.<init>(AnnotationConfiguration.java:108)
 at InsertData.main(InsertData.java:11)
```

DataProvider.java

```html
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="dataprovider")
public class DataProvider {
 
 @Id @GeneratedValue
 @Column(name="id")
 private int user_id;
 @Column(name="name")
 private String user_name;
 @Column(name="description")
 private String user_desc;
 
 
 public int getUser_id() {
  return user_id;
 }
 public void setUser_id(int user_id) {
  this.user_id = user_id;
 }
 public String getUser_name() {
  return user_name;
 }
 public void setUser_name(String user_name) {
  this.user_name = user_name;
 }
 public String getUser_desc() {
  return user_desc;
 }
 public void setUser_desc(String user_desc) {
  this.user_desc = user_desc;
 }
 

}
```

InsertData.java

```html
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="dataprovider")
public class DataProvider {
 
 @Id @GeneratedValue
 @Column(name="id")
 private int user_id;
 @Column(name="name")
 private String user_name;
 @Column(name="description")
 private String user_desc;
 
 
 public int getUser_id() {
  return user_id;
 }
 public void setUser_id(int user_id) {
  this.user_id = user_id;
 }
 public String getUser_name() {
  return user_name;
 }
 public void setUser_name(String user_name) {
  this.user_name = user_name;
 }
 public String getUser_desc() {
  return user_desc;
 }
 public void setUser_desc(String user_desc) {
  this.user_desc = user_desc;
 }
 

}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<hibernate-configuration>

<session-factory>
 
<!-- Related to the connection START -->
<property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver </property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb </property>
<property name="connection.user">root </property>
<property name="connection.password">root</property>
<!-- Related to the connection END -->
 
<!-- Related to hibernate properties START -->
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="dialet">org.hibernate.dialet.MYSQLDialet</property>
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
<!-- Related to hibernate properties END-->
 
<!-- Related to mapping START-->
<mapping resource="user.hbm.xml" />
<!-- Related to the mapping END -->
 
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Which binaries you use?

Comment: I dont see namingStrategy field in any of your code.

Comment: and there is no something like this in my code :)

Comment: http://way2java.com/hibernate/hibernate-simple-example-explained-basics-to-insert-a-record/ follow this. Hope it is similar to your code...

Comment: @SkyWalker i want to use annotations not xml mapping :)

Comment: Would you please share your pom.xml file? @mmmm

Comment: @SkyWalker i did plz have a look

Answer (score 0):

For annotations, You need to change `user.hbm.xml` to your `packagename.classname`

```
<!-- Related to mapping START-->
<mapping resource="user.hbm.xml" />
<!-- Related to the mapping END -->
```

You have to use your package name on that case.

```
<mapping class="yourPackageName.DataProvider" />
```

where,

> yourPackageName = com.something.
>
> DataProvider = your class name

Related Link: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-relationship-example-annotation/